# Java client C++ server data send/receive problem

Tags: java, c++, sockets, server

I have created a simple java client, and a c++ server. I am trying to transfer some data from the client to the server. The problem is that when the server receives the data it shows some bad symbols, and also when the server returns some response to the java client, i see those bad symbols again. Could you help me to solve that problem..

***java client***

```
 public Client(String host, int port) {
        try {
            String serverHostname = new String(host);

            System.out.println("Connecting to host " + serverHostname + " on port " + port + ".");

            Socket echoSocket = null;
            PrintWriter out = null;
            BufferedReader in = null;

            try {
                echoSocket = new Socket(serverHostname, port);
                out = new PrintWriter(echoSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(echoSocket.getInputStream()));
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                System.err.println("Unknown host: " + serverHostname);
                System.exit(1);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("Unable to get streams from server");
                System.exit(1);
            }

            /** {@link UnknownHost} object used to read from console */
            BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

            while (true) {
                System.out.print("client: ");

                String userInput = stdIn.readLine();
                /** Exit on 'q' char sent */
                if ("q".equals(userInput)) {
                    break;
                }
                out.println(userInput);
                System.out.println("server: " + in.readLine());
            }

            /** Closing all the resources */
            out.close();
            in.close();
            stdIn.close();
            echoSocket.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

***c++ server***

```
int main()
{
    SOCKET ConSock;
    SOCKET ListenSock;
    SOCKADDR_IN address;
    int addsize = sizeof(address);

    long ok;
    char MESSAGE[200];

    WSAData WSD;
    WORD DllVersion = MAKEWORD(2, 1);

    ok = WSAStartup(DllVersion, &WSD);

    ConSock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,NULL);
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("10.64.15.3");
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_port = htons(10102);

    ListenSock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,NULL);

    bind(ListenSock,(SOCKADDR*)&address,sizeof(address));
    listen(ListenSock,SOMAXCONN);

    cout<<"Waiting for connection\n";

    while(1)
    {
        if(ConSock = accept(ListenSock,(SOCKADDR*)&address,&addsize))
        {

            ok = recv(ConSock,MESSAGE,sizeof(MESSAGE),NULL);

            string msg;
            msg = MESSAGE;

            cout<<"Client says:\t"<<msg;
            string reply;
            cout<<"\nEnter reply:";
            cin>>reply;

            const char* rep = reply.c_str();

            ok = send(ConSock,rep,1024,NULL);

        }

    }
}
```

Here is a picture of the input that i am getting from the client:
[c++ server image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNxjk.png)

Comment: 'bad symbols' sounds like character encoding issues. What encoding are you using (at both ends).

Comment: The issue is that you didn't specify the length anywhere and didn't null terminate the string you send

Comment: @PeterT i've specified the length in the c++ server

Comment: @K.Krunk There is no length specified here `msg = MESSAGE;`

Comment: `if(ok>0){ msg.assign(MESSAGE, ok); }` seems more apropriate, renaming `ok` to something like `bytesRead` might help with clarity

Answer (score 0):

Java character is two bytes. If you encode/decode it on the way out/in it will probably work (given you communicate the string length correctly as well, I have not checked).

```
StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1.encode(chars).array() -> byte array
StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1.decode(bytes).array() -> char array
```

Next thing that will break as soon as you start sending things other than text or choose to send unicode around and use wstring on the C++ side -- Java is using network byte order, C++ - host byte order (opposite to Java on x86). That's one of reasons.

One last piece of advice - make it work eiter Java-Java or C++-C++ first (whichever language you speak better), then switch to debugging the mix Java-C++.

Comment: Actualy my purpose is to comunicate through XML, but how could i encode the string that is been sent from the client ?

Comment: The Java way would be to use `Netty` + `XStream` or `JAXB`/`CXF` straight away, and not code the networking yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You just don't length check the buffers anywhere on the C++ side.

in this part

```
        ok = recv(ConSock,MESSAGE,sizeof(MESSAGE),NULL);

        string msg;
        msg = MESSAGE;
```

you just assign to `msg` all of the bytes until it sees a 0 but you never null terminated it, so it just prints the random stuff in memory. This is by the way also a potential buffer overflow.

Something more appropriate might be

```
        auto byte_count = recv(ConSock,MESSAGE,sizeof(MESSAGE),NULL);

        string msg;
        if(byte_cout > 0 )
        {
            msg.assign(MESSAGE, byte_count);
        }
```

Something similar is done when you send the whole buffer here:

```
        cin>>reply;
        const char* rep = reply.c_str();
        ok = send(ConSock,rep,1024,NULL);
```

You also have a potential buffer overflow by always sending 1024 bytes regardless of how large you buffer was.

Something like this might be better

```
        cin>>reply;
        ok = send(ConSock,reply.c_str(),reply.size(),NULL);
```

**Edit:** full programs with a little more well-defined "end of message" state would be a little like this

Java

```
public Client(String host, int port) {
    try {
        String serverHostname = new String(host);

        System.out.println("Connecting to host " + serverHostname + " on port " + port + ".");

        Socket echoSocket = null;
        PrintWriter out = null;
        BufferedReader in = null;

        try {
            echoSocket = new Socket(serverHostname, port);
            out = new PrintWriter(echoSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(echoSocket.getInputStream()));
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.err.println("Unknown host: " + serverHostname);
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Unable to get streams from server");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        /** {@link UnknownHost} object used to read from console */
        BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        while (true) {
            System.out.print("client: ");

            String userInput = stdIn.readLine();
            /** Exit on 'q' char sent */
            if ("q".equals(userInput)) {
                break;
            }
            out.println(userInput);
            //send a newline as a marker for "message is over"
            out.write('\n');
            System.out.println("server: " + in.readLine());
        }

        /** Closing all the resources */
        out.close();
        in.close();
        stdIn.close();
        echoSocket.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

C++ side

```
int main()
{
    SOCKET ConSock;
    SOCKET ListenSock;
    SOCKADDR_IN address;
    int addsize = sizeof(address);

    long ok;
    char MESSAGE[200];

    WSAData WSD;
    WORD DllVersion = MAKEWORD(2, 1);

    ok = WSAStartup(DllVersion, &WSD);

    ConSock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,NULL);
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("10.64.15.3");
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_port = htons(10102);

    ListenSock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,NULL);

    bind(ListenSock,(SOCKADDR*)&address,sizeof(address));
    listen(ListenSock,SOMAXCONN);

    cout<<"Waiting for connection\n";

    while(1)
    {
        if(ConSock = accept(ListenSock,(SOCKADDR*)&address,&addsize))
        {
            string msg;
            bool message_finished = false;
            //read into msg until we read a newline at the end or we get an error
            while(!message_finished)
            {
                auto length_read = recv(ConSock,MESSAGE,sizeof(MESSAGE),NULL);
                if(length_read > 0)
                {
                    msg.append(MESSAGE,length_read);
                    message_finished = msg[msg.size()-1] == '\n';
                }
                else if(length_read < 0)
                {
                   //don't continue to just endlessly loop on error
                   message_finished = true;
                }
            }

            cout<<"Client says:\t"<<msg;
            string reply;
            cout<<"\nEnter reply:";
            cin>>reply;
            //append a newline at the end to mark the end of the message
            reply+='\n';
            ok = send(ConSock, reply.c_str(), reply.size(),NULL);

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: That's great, but now when i response to the client(java app) the server stops, and there is no response :/

Comment: You sure the issue is on the server side? Because to me it looks like your java program is waiting until it gets a newline with `in.readLine()` but you never send one in the server. Maybe clarify how the actual protocol is supposed to work, because currently how much of an actual Incoming message is read on C++ side is completely arbitrary and you can easily deadlock it in many other ways like sending more than 200 characters from the java side.

Comment: The problem is that i am very new to socket programming, how could i increase the size of string input to the server, so that there won't be any deadlock, and how should i change the java app to receive the server response properly.

Comment: I added some minimally modified example, which I did not try to compile or verify and it still has some issues like ignoring errors on send (which might lead to large message replies not being send). But I think this is already more than the original question was asking for, which was just "how do I get rid of these bad symbols?"  Without understanding what the actual issue is, the code won't help you much.

Comment: You should also note that you are operating on two different levels of abstraction on both sides. On the C++ side you're using raw sockets and on the Java side you're using a buffered input/output stream library. Maybe a network library like `asio` would be more appropriate on the C++ side. It's just not part of the C++ standard library, so maybe look into that if you don't want to hand-code all the minor details of buffering, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, but even with the code you typed, the client doesn't receive the server response .. ;(

Comment: Right, I had the newline in the java program at the wrong place

Comment: why after 1 circulation, the client cannot send more requests to the server ?

Comment: Because that's how you wrote the server. After it's done sending the reply it blocks and waits for a new connection with `accept`.